# Get Id or Url from a Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-ads-api

I'm trying to make my life easier when creating Adwords reports and need to get two accounts data in to the same Google spreadsheet.

The data(ie columns etc) is the same for both accounts. The only thing I get stuck at is how to find the document that the first script on account A creates when running the script on account B.

If I could get the spreadsheet URL or ID it would be easy but I can't figure out how to get it. I know the name of the document but can't figure out if I can use that.

Answer (score 3):

To get the Spreadsheet Id just create an
Apps Script function and retrieve it by making the call

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId()
```

Or you can find it by name

```
function findSpreadsheetByName(name) {
  var iterator = DriveApp.getFilesByName(name);
  while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    var file = iterator.next();
    if(file.getMimeType() == MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS) {
      return file.getId();
    }
  }
  
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. But the problem I have is to get the right ID. I have the first script creating the report called "Weekly report 20140120" and then I have another script in a different account that has to access this document. And since it will create a new document every week I cant know the ID right?

Comment: The Id of the new document?

Comment: Yeah, I got an account A in adowrds where I put the first script in. When that runs it creates a spreadsheet with data called "Weekly report 20140121". Then i got a account B where I want to put a script that put the same data into the spreadsheet that account A created. So basiclly I am wondering if you can find and write to a spreadsheet using something like: spreadsheetApp.getSpreadsheetName("Weeekly Report 20140121"). Since I won't know what the ID or Url will be.